# Unable to make for buildroot (checking for suffix of object files... configure: error)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, toolchain, buildroot, binutils

I am trying to make buildroot toolchain for cross compilation on Raspberry Pi. ( using buildroot-2016.11)

When I run make, I receive the following error:

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/usr/RPi/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/host-binutils-2.26.1':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
buildroot-2016.11/output/build/host-binutils-2.26.1'
```

The config.log from the error window is as below:

```
ccache: error: Failed to create temporary file for  /auto/ccache/tmp/tmp.cpp_stderr: Permission denied
    112 configure:4591: $? = 1
    113 configure: failed program was:
    114 | /* confdefs.h */
    122 |
    123 | int
    124 | main ()
    125 | {
    126 |
    127 |   ;
    128 |   return 0;
    129 | }

    130 configure:4605: error: in `/usr/RPi/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/host-binutils-2.26.1':
    131 configure:4608: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

Comment: formatting changes

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't have write permission in the `/auto/ccache/` directory. You can use `sudo chown -R YOURUSERNAME:YOURUSERNAME /auto/ccache/` to set proper access permissions.

You set the ccache directory `BR2_CCACHE_DIR` (either in the environment or in the config file) to `/auto/ccache`. You need to make sure that you have write permission to that directory.